# Which dust size causes most damage to turbine engines?

Tags: jet-engine, aircraft-maintenance, foreign-object-damage

I'm conducting some research on my bachelor's thesis on predictive maintenance and I have so far not been able to find a solution to the following question:

***Which size of dust is more damaging to the engine when it comes to ingested dust?***

So far I have found some papers covering the topic or moderately related to it but I can't seem to find a precise answer directly relating particle size and damage *(i.e. from 200µm to 500 µm the damage is severe but under 200 µm much smaller damage is presented; for particles bigger than 1 mm no damage is presented as they do not enter the turbines)*

I hope someone has found some insight on this topic.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you specifically asking about damage to the *turbine blades*? My naïve understanding would be that the *fan* or *compressor blades* would be damaged more by dust, but maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: Any damage is relevant. I just figured out that it would be easier to relate particle size with turbine damage, but i might be mistaken.

Comment: OK, I phrased the title a bit more generic now. Feel free to edit again if you need something more specific.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the type of dust has a much larger influence than the size. Volcanic ash is detrimental because of its low melting point, sand can be highly abrasive, but I can't imagine sawdust having any effect regardless of size.

Comment: Yes the type of dust makes a difference . Sodium Sulfate is not hard but can melt and cause "hot corrosion" on some of the lower alloy blades. Also there is variety of exotic blade coating materials used to protect them ; I believe from both oxidation and erosion. ,

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, @Sanchises. 
I will take that into consideration.

Comment: I appreciate your answer @blacksmith37. Do you know of any other heavily damaging aerosol to keep an eye on? Or where could one find such information?